# Excel. How to join tables by a column with sum?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to obtain column `F` in the following example

[image: Example]

Basically, I need to match the index, and return the value in column `B`, with the complication of having to return the sum in case there is more than one match for my index. I would normally just use `VLOOKUP`, but that only returns the first match, and I can think of some manual ways to deal with this, but I was wondering what the cleanest way is.

Comment: You're looking for `SUMIF`. Let us know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMIF. In this case you don't want to use a look up such as vlookup or index/match because you are performing a calculation over a group rather than returning a value.

In F1 Try: =sumif(A:A, E1, B:B) and then run this formula down